# How to extend/customize a bootstrap's class' descendants using SASS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, react-bootstrap

I want to create a custom table style by extending existing bootstrap style. The thing is, I only want to customize a specific descendant of the style. i.e., I want to make the header sticky by extending the `th` descendant selector's style by `position: 'sticky'; top: 0;`.

To this end, I added the following in the `custom.scss` file:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.my-custom-table {
  @extend .table-striped;
  @extend .table-bordered;
  th {
    position: 'sticky';
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

when I use that class in the rendering logic like below :

`<Table className='my-custom-table'/>`

The **header isn't sticky**. Note that if I use the style in each of the `th` cells, it works as expected.

Any help with where I have gone wrong is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to replace the ` > th ` with `tr > th` since the table does not have ` th ` as direct child.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Comment: no luck with that. I even tried > thead > tr > th just to be sure. That doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very silly mistake. I had to use `sticky` instead of `'sticky'` (notice the quotes) and that solved the problem.